# How do you make a marker like this in ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, bootstrap-5

I need to make a bold line like this to li in a bulleted list.

[image]

Tried border , but it does not display correctly. How can this be done quickly and easily?

Below is my code structure

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: by 'border' do you mean that you also tried 'border-bottom'?

Comment: You could look into using a pseudo element.

Comment: Are you referring to the red line on the left, or the grey line on the bottom? What have you tried?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try

```
box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 0 red;
```

You could also try **:before** and **content: ' ';** to add a colored block before the listed item and add rounded corners to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).